# PaperJS to get co-ordinates of shapes(circle, rect, etc.,)

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I have created a simple image marker using paperJS. Now i have to add a undo option, to create that i need to store all the co-ordinate position and a button to undo. How can i do this can anyone help me. This is my script.

```
function onMouseDrag(event) {
            if(set == 1){
                    path = new Path.Circle({
                        center: event.point,
                        radius: (event.downPoint - event.point).length,
                        fillColor: null,
                        strokeColor: '#e9e9ff',
                        strokeWidth: 1
                    });
            }else if(set == 2){
                var rectangle = new Rectangle(event.point, event.downPoint);
                var path = new Path.Rectangle(rectangle);
                path.fillColor = null;
                path.strokeColor = '#e9e9ff';
                path.strokeWidth = 1;   
            }else if(set == 3){
                var path = new Path.Line({
                        from: event.point,
                        to : event.downPoint,
                        strokeColor: 'black'
                    });
            }else if(set == 4){
                        var path = new PointText({
                        point: event.point,
                        content: 'The contents of the point text',
                        fillColor: 'black',
                        fontSize: 25
                    }); 
            }
                  path.removeOnDrag();
        };

        function onMouseUp(event) {
                circles.push(path);
        };
```

And this is my html.

```
<div class="menu-list">
    <input type="button" value="Circle" onClick="return set=1;">
    <input type="button" value="Rectangle" onClick="return set=2;">
    <input type="button" value="Line" onClick="return set=3;">
    <input type="button" value="Text" onClick="return set=4;">
</div>
<div class="img-mark">
    <canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
</div>
<div class="mark-list">

</div>
```

Comment: As you're not reordering the shapes, why not have the undo button remove the last child of the circles array?

Comment: If i create a first circle it should show as circle1 and for second circle2 so that i can delete either circle1 or circle2. If you cant understand shall i give a reference site.

Comment: Yes, a reference site would be welcome

Comment: [See here](http://www.picozu.com/editor/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, if I understood what you want, but try this:
You can select a specific path or shape with help of the hitResult:

```
var hitResult = project.hitTest(event.point, hitOptions);
if (!hitResult) {
    return;
} else {
    path = hitResult.item;
}
```

see this example: http://paperjs.org/examples/hit-testing/ 
and then you can call `path.remove()` (http://paperjs.org/reference/path) when the user hits delete

PS: instead of using `set == x`you should have a look at http://paperjs.org/reference/tool . You can define different tools with `circleTool = new Tool();` and than call `circleTool.activate()` and `circleTool.onMouseDown = function() {...}`